# Need to constantly delete node_modules for Angular 9 app to work

Tags: node.js, angular

I'm very new to web development and I'm trying to get familiar with building Angular forms. I'm running in to a problem where every time I start up an Angular project using `npm start` or `ng serve` and go to the localhost, it gives me an error "Cannot GET /".

If I close everything down, delete node_modules within the project folder, run `npm install` then `npm start` again, it will work. If I close the terminal and try to run the project again, I get back to the same error. Basically I can only run the project exactly one time before I have to go and repeat the process of deleting node_modules etc (which is even a pain in itself as I haven't found a quick way to delete node_modules.)

I'm using Windows and the April 2020 release of VS Code and Angular 9. Please let me know if I can provide any information re: code, files etc., as I said I'm pretty new to this and not really sure where I could look to try to fix this. Thank you!

Update: Here is what I have in the terminal. The error is at the bottom and it has to do with MatDialogRef, but to be honest I've just ignored this because I get this same error regardless, even if my project opens properly. I believe this error is caused by some changes they made to Angular 9, but I'm not sure how to fix it.

Update 2: I edited the path of MatDialogRef to @angular/materials/dialog, which fixed that error, but now I'm getting a whole bunch of errors of the same type which were not occurring before. Please see below.

```
ERROR in src/app/app-layer/app-layer.component.html:2:35 - error TS2339: Property 'isLinear' does not exist on type 'AppLayerComponent'.

2 <mat-vertical-stepper [linear] = "isLinear" #stepper>
                                    ~~~~~~~~

  src/app/app-layer/app-layer.component.ts:6:16
    6   templateUrl: './app-layer.component.html',
                     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    Error occurs in the template of component AppLayerComponent.
```

Below here is the original error which I fixed by adding `/dialog`

```
> app-frontend@0.0.0 start C:\Users\u123\Documents\Angular\app-frontend
> ng serve

chunk {main} main.js, main.js.map (main) 2.04 kB [initial] [rendered]
chunk {polyfills} polyfills.js, polyfills.js.map (polyfills) 700 bytes [initial] [rendered]
chunk {runtime} runtime.js, runtime.js.map (runtime) 6.15 kB [entry] [rendered]
chunk {styles} styles.js, styles.js.map (styles) 1.28 MB [initial] [rendered]
chunk {vendor} vendor.js, vendor.js.map (vendor) 339 kB [initial] [rendered]
Date: 2020-05-20T18:57:35.818Z - Time: 16760ms

ERROR in node_modules/gcui/lib/delete-confirmation-dialog/delete-confirmation-dialog.component.d.ts:1:30 - error TS2306: File 'C:/Users/u123/Documents/Angular/app-frontend/node_modules/@angular/material/index.d.ts' is not a module.

1 import { MatDialogRef } from '@angular/material';
                               ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

** Angular Live Development Server is listening on localhost:4200, open your browser on http://localhost:4200/ **
```

Comment: can you also show us error logs in terminal and console

Comment: I edited the post with a bit more detail and put the terminal output. What do you mean by error logs in console? Thanks.

Comment: try clearing cache :delete node modules-> then npm cache clean --force->npm install

Answer (score 0):

That seems to be a breaking change with Angular 9.

Check this issue: https://github.com/angular/components/issues/17503

Try changing your import to use the specific components. 
Example, if you are using material button then:

```
import { MatButtonModule } from '@angular/material/button';
```

Comment: I made this change. So that error goes away, but then I get a bunch of other errors. I'll update my post.

Comment: Ok. Do you mind posting the content of `app-layer.component.ts`? From the error it looke like the `isLinear` variable is not present.